# trying to send an email using the java mail but it's not working

Tags: jakarta-mail, jsf-2.2

I have a jsf page in my application where the user should send an email to the administrator in order to reset his password and login. I did write the code and added the jars to the buildpath but when i click on the send button the page is refreshed and the email is not sent to the destination and there is no exception displayed i can't figure out what's wrong 
Updated code according to RamiQ answer
 this is the managedbean code

```
                  @ManagedBean(name="sendMail")
                  @SessionScoped
               public class SendMail implements java.io.Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String to = "toadress";
private String objet = "Compte  inaccessible";
private String body = "Mon compte "
        + getNom()
        + " "
        + getPrenom()
        + " n'est plus accessible.Veuillez s'il vous plaît réinitialiser mes cordonnées et les envoyer à mon email "
        + getFrom();
private String from = "fromadress";
private String smtpServer = "smtp.orange.tn";
private String nom;
private String prenom;

public void send() {

        Properties props =new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpServer);
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
        try {
             Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
                msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
                msg.setSubject(objet);
                msg.setSentDate(new Date());
                msg.setText("Mail Body ....");
                Transport.send(msg);
        System.out.println("Message Sent Ok");
        FacesMessage msg2 = new FacesMessage("E-mail envoyé avec succés");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg2);
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is the page code

```
        <h:form id="f1">
            <br></br>
            <div class="centre">
                <p:inputText placeholder="Nom" required="true" id="nom"
                    value="#{sendMail.nom}"
                    validator="#{AdministrateurBean.checkAdmin}"></p:inputText>
                <h:messages style="color:red" for="nom"/>
            </div>
            <div class="centre">
                <p:inputText placeholder="Prénom" required="true"
                    value="#{sendMail.prenom}" id="prenom" ></p:inputText>
                <h:messages style="color:red" for="prenom"/>
            </div>

            <div class="centre">
                <p:inputText placeholder="xyz@exemple.com" required="true" id="email"></p:inputText>
                <h:messages style="color:red" for="email"/>
            </div>
            <div class="centre">
                <p:button value="Envoyer" size="30" style="width:207px"
                    action="#{sendMail.send}" update="f1"></p:button>
            </div>

        </h:form>
    </div>
```

Comment: We need more information than "it doesn't work".  See the [debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html).

Comment: ok i used the first tip and set the debug to true because there is no exception generated it's just not sending the mail and refreshing the page instead

Comment: I am guessing that you mean 'actionListener' in your JSF page. Can you try setting a debug point at the sendMail action and see if it is being invoked or not?

Comment: I am sorry i am a newbie where should i exactly set the debug point in sendMail cause as i undrestand i put it in the send method and still i am getting nothing in the log

Comment: What's the debug output show exactly?  Can you post it here?  Do you get the "Message Sent Ok" message from your program?

Comment: no it doesn't show anything and i don't get "Message Sent Ok" from the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... send (String smtpServer,String to,String rom, String objet,String body){
```

The name of the Parameter FromAddress is "**rom**", but you use it as "**from**".

in generally, doing it this way should work:

```
String to = "sendToMailAddress";
String from = "sendFromMailAddress";

String host = "smtp.yourisp....";


Properties props = new Properties();


props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

try {

    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);


    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
    msg.setSubject("Test Subject");
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());


    msg.setText("Mail Body ....");


    Transport.send(msg);
}
catch (MessagingException mex) {
    mex.printStackTrace();
}
```

**UPDATE:** 
your action Method **doSendMail** won't be fired!
it has an actionevent parameter, this is only needed if this method is for actionlistener not for action, remove this parameter

```
public void doSendMail(ActionEvent e)
```

to

```
    public String doSendMail(){
    ....
    return null;

}
```

an action Method should return a Navigation outcome, if you want to navigate to the same page, then return null.

i don't know which JSF version you use, but in generally declare your managedbeans like this should work:

```
 @ManagedBean(name="sendMail")
 @SessionScoped
 public class SendMail implements java.io.Serializable{
```

Comment: i tried your code and i fixed the parameter but still its not working

Comment: @MeknessiHamida: i updated my answer, change your code as in my update!

Comment: i update my code as yours but it still not working and the weird thing about it is that after i click the send button the page gets refreshed .Is there any additional configuration tos end the mail other then the code cause i only wrote the code i did no configuration on the server or anything like that ?

Comment: @MeknessiHamida: ok, read my update and change your code to that what i last updated in my answer

Comment: i did as you explained but still the same behavior. check my code update to see my current code

Comment: @MeknessiHamida, no you don't, your send Method has to have a return value as i pointed in my answer.

Comment: by the way, you have to use <p:commandButton action="#{sendMail.send}" value="Envoyer"/> instead of <p:button ...

Comment: After fixing the errors you told me about i try to send the email in the log file it show me that Message sent Ok but there is no message received in my email account

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45321/discussion-between-meknessihamida-and-rami-q)